# A simple play button for YouTube with JQuery

Tags: jquery, youtube, youtube-api

I want 2 simple buttons to play and stop a YouTube video. I tried something like this with jQuery and doesn't work.

1. Can anyone help me with a simple and clean solution to do a play
   button for a YouTube video?
2. Can I hide  the video in order to
   just hear the sound?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Carwu
http://jsfiddle.net/8kN6Z/34/

```
$(function(){

  $("#video").hide();          
  $("#escolta").click(function() {
    video.playVideo();
    //$("#video").playVideo();
    //$("#video").trigger('play');
    //$(".player").playVideo()

    });

  $("#pausa").click(function() {
    video.stopVideo();
    //$("#video").trigger('pause');
  });

});
```

CSS:

```
#escolta,#pausa{ font-family: Tahoma;letter-spacing:1px;font-size:11px;color: #666;width: 80px;text-align: center;height: 20px;line-height: 20px;background-color: #ccc;cursor: pointer;}
#escolta {position:absolute;top: 20px;left:20px;}
#pausa{position: absolute;top:20px;left: 150px;}​
#pausa{position: absolute;top:20px;left: 150px;}
#video{position:absolute;top:100px;left:20px;}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="escolta">escolta</div>
<div id="pausa">pausa</div>

<iframe id="video" width="640" height="360" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/4G1mundpq-Q?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: How much simpler can you get than clicking on the video?

Comment: @Blazemonger But that wouldn't be using the API as the question asks :)

Comment: 1-I want to hide the video and only hear the sound. 2-I want to customize the buttons to fit with the design of a page. What I show here is just an example simplified to help to explain the problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I revisted this one. Figured out some of the problems you were having.

Look at it working on JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8kN6Z/33/

Here is what you did wrong:

You weren't loading the Youtube Player API. Which you have to do manually even if you are using an iframe.

You weren't creating a function named onYouTubePlayerAPIReady.

You weren't creating an YT.Player object for your frame and setting the onReady event handler for that YT.Player object to your onPlayerReady function.

You didn't wait until inside your onPlayerReady callback function to set your click event handlers to the ready YT.Player object.

You set the Javascript API on JSFiddle to Mootools and then used CSS selector syntax with $('#id'). $$('#id') works with mootools but $('id') is the correct Mootools syntax. $('#id') is jQuery.

You wrapped the javascript in the onLoad method. Which doesn't work.

The YouTube Player API setup and function definitions needs to be defined at the top level.

The biggest problem is the missing type="text/html" and src scripting parameter &enablejsapi=1 property in the iframe tag. Without those none of the scripting works.

On Codepen you are using jQuery so this solution would have to be transliterated.

Problems I encounter with Mootools:
$('video').hide() doesn't work. Creating a .hideme class with display:none and calling $('video').addClass('hideme') at the end of the onPlayerReady callback function works just fine.

[JS Fiddle working example](http://jsfiddle.net/8kN6Z/33/)

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="escolta">escolta</div>
    <div id="pausa">pausa</div>
    <iframe id="video" type="text/html" width="640" height="360" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/4G1mundpq-Q?rel=0&enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#escolta, #pausa {
    font-family: Tahoma;
    letter-spacing:1px;
    font-size:11px;
    color: #666;
    width: 80px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#escolta {
    position:absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left:20px;
}
#pausa {
    position: absolute;
    top:20px;
    left: 150px;
}
#pausa {
    position: absolute;
    top:20px;
    left: 150px;
}
#video {
    position:absolute;
    top:100px;
    left:20px;
}
.hideme {
    display:none;
}
```

JS:

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "//www.youtube.com/player_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    new YT.Player('video', {
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady
        }
    });
}
function onPlayerReady(event) {
    $("escolta").addEvent('click', function () {
        event.target.playVideo();
    });
    $("pausa").addEvent('click', function () {
        event.target.stopVideo();
    });
    $('video').addClass('hideme');
}
```

Updated info for jQuery follows:

I saved a new tested working jQuery jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8kN6Z/47/

The only change is the two lines where the buttons are selected by id in the javascript portion. The rest of the javascript is using the javascript built in DOM methods.

JQuery JS:

```
var player;
function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('video', {
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady
      }
    });
}
function onPlayerReady(event){
  event.target.playVideo();
    $("#escolta").on('click', function() {
      player.playVideo();
    });
    $("#pausa").on('click', function() {
      player.stopVideo();
    });
  }
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "//www.youtube.com/player_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but my jsfiddle has the mootools lybrary by accident (it seems that is the default in jsfiddle) As I say in the title I need jQuery. I have no idea of Mootools and I don't know how to adapt your code to jQuery. Can you do it with jQuery please. It would be great!

Comment: I updated the answer with the jQuery code and a link to the tested working jQuery jsFiddle.

Comment: Your example (fiddle) is not working on Mac OS X. Neither in chrome nor Firefox. But it's OK on Windows

Comment: @freegnu Your fiddle(http://jsfiddle.net/8kN6Z/47/) isn't working on IOS (iphone, ipad) and shows this error "If playback doesn't begin shortly, try restarting your device". Do you have any suggestions how can this be fixed and autoplayed on IOS ?

Answer (score 1):

You won't need to use jQuery selectors to get the player, you should have specified an ID for the player "e.g. 'player'". From this point you can simply do `player.playVideo();`

https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

edit:
To hide the player, you can just use $("#player").hide(); as it will hide the iFrame :)

Comment: I think it doesn't work or there is something I don't understand. Can you show it here?  http://jsfiddle.net/8kN6Z/5/

Answer (score 1):

Stick this in the html part. Sorry about the formatting. I'm in a rush.

```
<body>
<div id="escolta">escolta</div>
<div id="pausa">pausa</div>
<div id="player"></div>
<script>
  // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
  var tag = document.createElement('script');
  tag.src = "//www.youtube.com/player_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
  // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
  //    after the API code downloads.
  var player;
  function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: '360',
      width: '640',
      videoId: '4G1mundpq-Q',
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
  }
  // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    //event.target.playVideo();
    $("#escolta").click(function() {
        player.playVideo();
    });
    $("#pausa").click(function() {
        player.stopVideo();
    });
  }
  // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
  //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
  //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
  var done = false;
  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    //if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
      //setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
      //done = true;
    //}
  }
  function stopVideo() {
    player.stopVideo();
  }
</script>
</body>​
```

Comment: Please try it in a fiddle, codepen... I think it doesn't work? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Carwu
http://jsfiddle.net/8kN6Z/

Answer (score 1):

I create a just simple function and its 100% work. Simple and Fast :)

Here is the code

```
<div class="col-xs-12 vdoframe"><img src="images/vdoimg.jpg" style="cursor:pointer" id="videoimg" />
<iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/9-F7fkAz5G0?rel=0&enablejsapi=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" id="video"></iframe>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){

                $('#videoimg').on('click', function(){

                    $(this).css({
                        'z-index':'1'
                    });

                    $('#video').css('z-index', '2');
                    $("#video")[0].src += "&autoplay=1";
        ev.preventDefault();

                })

})


    </script>
```